# Using Class Method for Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called "Project" and a class method called published? where I determined whether a project is published.  I'd like to create a scope based on this class method.  What is the correct syntax?

This is what my Project.rb looks like:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :images_attributes, :ancestry, :user_id, :built, :remix

def published?
    published = false
    if remix_id.blank?
      # check if the remix has been updated
      if updated_at != created_at
        published = true
      end
    else
      # for non remixed projects, projects are published if the title has been updated and a picture has been uploaded
      if title.starts_with("Untitled")
        if images.count > 0
          published = true
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return published
end
```

I tried:

**`scope :published, where(published? => true)`**

**`scope :published, where(:published? => true)`**

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to avoid creating a column for my Project model, but I created one called published and just set its value based on the published? method.  I then update the column accordingly and use it for the scope.